# Error creating peer channel Amazon Managed Blockchain Hyperledger Fabric v1.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca, amazon-managed-blockchain

I hope someone could help me with the following problem.

I am using Amazon Managed Blockchain with the framework Hyperledge Fabric v1.4 and I followed this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/latest/hyperledger-fabric-dev/get-started-create-channel.html.

This is the error I get when I try to create the channel with that command line:

- Command line:
  docker exec cli peer channel create -c mychannel -f /opt/home/mychannel.pb -o $ORDERER --cafile /opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem --tls
- Error:
  2022-01-17 10:34:47.356 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
  Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel creation transaction for new channel 'mychannel', could not succesfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

The admin certificate is in a folder "admin-msp".

My configxt.yaml (I did not get any error executing a previous step with "docker exec cli configtxgen -outputCreateChannelTx /opt/home/mychannel.pb -profile OneOrgChannel -channelID mychannel --configPath /opt/home/"):

Organizations:

```
- &Org1
   
    Name: m-Q37N3LRUKNFDXBZ7GARMYFBYIE

    ID: m-Q37N3LRUKNFDXBZ7GARMYFBYIE
   
    Policies: &Org1Policies
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1.member')"
            # If your MSP is configured with the new NodeOUs, you might
            # want to use a more specific rule like the following:
            # Rule: "OR('Org1.admin', 'Org1.peer', 'Org1.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1.member')"
            # If your MSP is configured with the new NodeOUs, you might
            # want to use a more specific rule like the following:
            # Rule: "OR('Org1.admin', 'Org1.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1.admin')"
    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration.
    MSPDir: /opt/home/admin-msp
    # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used for
    # cross-org gossip communication. Note, this value is only encoded in
    # the genesis block in the Application section context.
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: 127.0.0.1
          Port: 7051
```

Capabilities:

```
Channel: &ChannelCapabilities


    V1_4_3: true

    V1_3: false

    V1_1: false

Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities

    V1_4_2: true

    V1_1: false


Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    
    V1_4_2: true

    V1_3: false

    V1_2: false

    V1_1: false
```

Channel: &ChannelDefaults

```
Policies:
    # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
```

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

```
Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
    LifecycleEndorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Endorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Profiles:
OneOrgChannel:
<<: *ChannelDefaults
Consortium: AWSSystemConsortium
Application:
<<: *ApplicationDefaults
Organizations:
- <<: *Org1

My  docker-compose-cli.yaml file:

version: '2'

services:

cli:

```
container_name: cli

image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:1.4

tty: true

environment:

  - GOPATH=/opt/gopath

  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock

  - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info # Set logging level to debug for more verbose logging

  - CORE_PEER_ID=cli

  - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10

  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true

  - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/home/managedblockchain-tls-chain.pem

  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=$Member

  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/home/admin-msp

  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=$MyPeerNodeEndpoint

working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

command: /bin/bash

volumes:

    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/

    - /home/ec2-user/fabric-samples/chaincode:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/

    - /home/ec2-user:/opt/home
```

Thanks in advance :).